# How to send emails with voting buttons programmatically?

Tags: outlook, rtf

Is there a way to add voting buttons to an automatically generated emails (viewed in Outlook?)    Is there RTF syntax available?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the MailItem.VotingOptions property?